# Why is hexadecimal bytes data b'\x35' being interpreted as b'5' in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyserial

I am working with a set of hexadecimal data. I am using bytes type for the data.
For example
I am having the data as  `b'\x35'`, `b'\xA6'`, `b'\x12'`, `b'\x26'`

When I print each of these hexadecimal characters, I am getting the output as `b'5'`, `b'\xa6'`, `b'\x12'`, `b'&'` correspondingly

I am getting `b'\xa6'`, `b'\x12'` as the same. But I am getting a different output when I print `b'\x35'` and `b'\x26'`.

Can you please tell me how do I fix this issue? I want my output to be the same as the input .

Comment: The textual representation of bytes objects displays the values corresponding to printable characters in ASCII as these characters. Your input and output are just representations of the bytes.

Comment: Run `man ascii` and look for `35` in the hex table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting `b'5'` when you print `b'\x35'` is because `0x35` is the hexadecimal representation of the number 5 (in the ASCII encoding). Python just interprets `b'\x35'` as 5. So when you get `b'5'` its the exact same thing as `b'\x35'`. The same goes for any ascii character. For example if I typed in:

```
print(b'\x61')
```

I would get `a` as the output because `0x61` is the ascii code for the letter a. Essentially, `b'5'` is exactly the same as `b'\x35'`, so nothing needs changing. Just use the value as is, since it will work fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to disable the python interpreting hexadecimal to ASCII? Because the application I'm working currently works only with the hex interpretation

Comment: I suppose you could convert the ascii character to a hexadecimal integer, but there is no way to disable it. You could do that with: `hex(int(ord(b'\x35')))`. This gives a result that takes the form: `0x35`. However, it is a string. So if you wanted a hexadecimal interpretation of the number, you could do it like that. However, it does not matter. If you type `b'\x35' == b'5'` into your python interpreter, it will return `True`. It won't matter. They are the same thing, and will work. If you could post some of your code in your answer, I may be able to help more.